# how to connect intelliJ to oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I have installed oracle and created table in it. now I want to connect intellij idea to oracle. I have added classes12.jar to libraries, but I can't connect my code to oracle. what should I do? my code is:

```
package example;

import java.sql.*;
public class first {
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;
    public first()throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL","maryam","myjava123");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    }

    public void insert() throws Exception
    {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO T1 (ID,NAME) VALUES (1,'ALI')");

    }
    public void close() throws Exception
    {
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        first mari=new first();
        mari.insert();
    }
}
```

and the Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at example.first.<init>(first.java:9)
    at example.first.main(first.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: The classname of the diver is not properly written moreover it is not even the right one, use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead

Comment: I changed it, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver");
//--------------------------------^-- here is the issue
```

to

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

or

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Additionally, check if the driver jar file is really present in the classpath.

Comment: @maryam - Is driver jar in the classpath? did you try `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`?

Comment: tnx for answering. I fixed it :-)

Comment: tnx for answering. I fixed it :-)   ... the problems were: 1-  classes12.jar file wasn't download completely and it had problem. 2- I have to change  "oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver" to "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" as you mentioned  3- the table that I had created in oracle had problem and I changed it....

Answer (score 0):

Use ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc7.jar in classpath. And also change oracleDriver to OracleDriver.